# What is the difference between hard and soft masked numpy arrays?

Tags: numpy, masked-array

I have been browsing the numpy docs for masked arrays (which I really like and use regularly) and found [numpy.ma.harden_mask](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.harden_mask.html) and [numpy.ma.soften_mask](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.soften_mask.html) which affect the [MaskedArray.hardmask](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.hardmask) attribute, but I can't find an explanation of that attribute's purpose.

Hence: What is the difference between hard and soft masked numpy arrays?

Comment: You might be more familiar withe masked_arrays than most of us, if you use them regularly.  I for one only use them to answer (beginner's questions).  Most of the `ma` code is written in Python - I don't think it has any compiled additions.  So comments in the function code might add information that's not in the docs.

Comment: I'd be interested to know too - I use masked arrays regularly as well, and had never heard of this ...a quick duckduckgo search turned up nothing explaining this at all.

Answer (score 2):

As @hpaulj wrote that the `ma` module is implemented in Python, I looked at the sources and indeed found answers:

> The numpy.ma implementation has a "hardmask" feature,
> which prevents values from ever being unmasked by assigning a value.
> This would be an internal array flag, named something like
> 'arr.flags.hardmask'.
>
> If the hardmask feature is implemented, boolean indexing could
> return a hardmasked array instead of a flattened array with the
> arbitrary choice of C-ordering as it currently does. While this
> improves the abstraction of the array significantly, it is not
> a compatible change.

The following documentation of the `hardmask` attribute could be found in my old checkout in `maskedarray.baseclass.rst`, but it vanished after updating, which explains why it is missing on the website:

> Returns whether the mask is hard (`True`) or soft (`False`).
> When the mask is hard, masked entries cannot be unmasked.

(I will send a PR suggesting that this sentence is restored and extended with ".. by element assigment".)

Here's a demonstration session:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.arange(10)
>>> m = numpy.ma.masked_array(x, x>5)
>>> assert not m.hardmask
>>> m[8] = 42
>>> m
masked_array(data=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, --, --, 42, --],
             mask=[False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
                   False,  True],
       fill_value=999999)
>>> hardened = numpy.ma.harden_mask(m)
>>> assert hardened.hardmask
>>> assert m.hardmask, 'harden_mask() affects AND returns the argument'
>>> m[9] = 23
>>> m
masked_array(data=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, --, --, 42, --],
             mask=[False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
                   False,  True],
       fill_value=999999)
>>> m[:] = 23
>>> m
masked_array(data=[23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, --, --, 23, --],
             mask=[False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
                   False,  True],
       fill_value=999999)
```

Comment: Followed up on in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19331